# How to form a list of lists?

Tags: python, python-2.7

My code below is extracting some portion from a file and displaying the result in separate lists.

I want to form a list of all these lists which were filtered out. I tried to form it in my code but when I am trying to print it out, I am getting an empty list.

```
import re
hand = open('mbox.txt')

for line in hand:
    my_list = list()
    line = line.rstrip()
    #Extracting out the data from file
    x=re.findall('^From .* ([0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9])', line)
    #checking the length and checking if the data is not present to the list
    if len(x) != 0 and x not in my_list:
        my_list.append(x[0])

print my_list
```

Filtered list is:

```
['15:46:24']
['15:03:18']
['14:50:18']
['11:37:30']
['11:35:08']
['11:12:37']
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just move `my_list=list()` to out of the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things to note. If you are repeatedly doing regex matching, I suggest you compile the pattern first and then do the matching. Also, you don't need to check length of a container manually to get its bool value - just do `if container:`. Use builtin filter to remove empty items. Or you can use a set that avoids duplicates automatically. I am also not sure why you are stripping the space characters before doing the regex match. Is that necessary?

```
import re
match = r"^From .* ([0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9])"

with open("mbox.txt") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        match = filter(None,re.findall(match, line))
        data.append(list(match))

print(data)
```

This is all you need to  get that list of lists. The use of list comprehension and filter made the code more compact.

Comment: Good points, however `re` module automatically caches regexps, so compiling them doesn't help as much as you might think.

Comment: @Renae I tried your answer but it is giving me only empty list as output.

Comment: Am I doing something wrong with the below code: 'import re

match = '^From .* ([0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9])'

with  open('mbox.txt') as f:
    data = filter(None, [re.findall(match, n) for n in f.readline()])

print (data)'